# Http basic authentication not working in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-security

I'm trying to understand how to secure SOAP web services with Spring Security. I see that `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` is created with the `antMatcher()` but my web service still not require any credentials. How to make it secured?

I have a guess that I not clearly understood patterns and I just have made wrong configuration, but I can't find where.

Web service URL: `http://localhost:8080/services/customer`

My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
                .authorities("ROLE_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/services/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);


        http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**UPD:** I didn't notice this yesterday, I just looked on the app and web services URLs, and they're different. It because Apache CXF web services start separately.

```
@Bean
public Endpoint endpoint() {
    EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), customerWebService );
    endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/services/customer");
    return endpoint;
}
```

And I haven't found any possible way how to start web services and publish endpoints inside the app. It looks like that's the point.

App: `http://localhost:8082/AppName/...`

Web services: `http://localhost:8080/services/customer`

Comment: What does your CustomFilter do?

Comment: See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication.

Comment: CustomFilter it just logging filter. I removed it for a while.

Comment: I've used this article as an example, but I stuck in specific of my app. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this configuration? If you have specific authorities per users, then you must require it on the given path.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/services/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
        .csrf().disable();


    http.addFilterAfter(new CustomFilter(),
            BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation to your answer?